# Selecting 3 objects from n objects placed circularly

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose n objects are placed along a circle at equal distances in how many ways can 3 objects be chosen so that no two of the chosen objects are adjacent or diametrically opposite.

**my attempt**
1.to calculate the case of n objects so none of chosen 3 are adjacent
suppose there are n-3 objects we can assume n-3 gaps (one gap after each object) now we have to select 3 gaps to place our objects (placing is equivalent to selecting).[ `{n-3 \choose 3}`
now we can do numbering of objects from 1 to n in n different ways.and each case is repeated (n-3) times so it becomes
n*`{n-3 \choose 3}`/(n-3)

1. to calculate the case when none objects are adjacent and two of them are diametrically opposite
   1.1 when n=odd there are no diametrically opposite points so we have our answer

1.2 when n is even we can proceed as follows-
we can select 2 objects from n-3 gaps and for 3rd object there are 2 places left [2*`{n-3 \choose 2}`
and by similar reasoning we get 2n*`{n-3 \choose 2}`/(n-3)
by summing up the above two cases we get the answer as
[n*(n-4)(n-5)/6]- [n*(n-4)] (n is even)
And [n*(n-4)(n-5)/6] ( n is odd)
can you tell what is wrong in my method

(In the original question n=40 is given)

Comment: I it will be easier todo $n$ odd first, since no points are diametrically opposite in that case.

Comment: In the original question n=40 is given. so my derived expression must be valid for n even but answer given is different.

Comment: Please don't shout in all caps in the title!

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Add that information to your question - a person shouldn't need  to read comments to know the context.

Comment: The  usual approach is to apply inclusion-exclusion, but it seems messy.

Comment: Thanks, edited the question

Comment: Yes principle of inclusion and exclusion is inedeed very messy

Comment: Are the objects distinguishable as in does rotation matter? Like is choosing $1,5,7$ the same as $2,6,8$?

Comment: Yea they are distinguishable choosing 1,5,7 is not as same as choosing 2,6,8

Answer (score 0):

If you have $n$ units around the table (the case when you do not have diametrically opposite units), you can use Kaplansky's theorem. When it comes to the other case, you can do this: Choose the first unit arbitrarily. Since you cannot take the diametrically opposite unit or the 2 places besides the chosen unit, you have just divided your table into 2 parts. Divide the problem into two cases: 1.) The remaining two units are in the same part of the table (use Kaplansky's theorem for that part of the table). 2.) The remaining two units are in different parts of the table (choose a single unit in the arbitrary remaining part of the table, and then choose another one in the last remaining part. In the last remaining part, you will exclude the one seat that is diametrical to the second unit chosen.)
***EDIT:***
Kaplansky's theorem (1943.): Let $k,n,v \in \mathbb{N}_0$, n>kv. The number of subsets $S \subset \{1,2,...,n\}$, such as $x \neq y$, $v<|x-y|<n-v$, is equal to: $g_v(n,k)=\frac{n}{n-kv}{n-kv \choose k}$. In your problem $v=1$ and $k=3$.
\newline
Other theorem also useful for this problem (for the part when your other 2 units are in the same part): Let $k \geq 0$, $n \geq 1$, $v\geq -1$ are whole numbers. Number of ordered $(a_1,...,a_k) $ of the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ such as $a_{j+1}-a_j > v$, for $j=1,2,...,k-1$ is $f_v(n,k)={n-(k-1)v \choose k}$, for $n\geq (k-1)v$. In your case, $v=1$. You will figure out the other parameters.

Comment: is there any other solution
as I am not aware of "kaplansky's theorem"  as well as by using your idea i tried to calculate the answer but the answer is heavily overcounted

Comment: I have added two required theorems to the answer. If you do not want to use Kaplansky's theorem, you can choose first person and then use the other theorem I have mentioned to put other two. be careful with diametrically opposite seats for the remaining 2 units, since the number of remaining seats will be an odd number.